# How to remotly access a custom wampserver's virtual host in a local network?

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, remote-access, wampserver

I use *Wampserver 3.0.6* under *windows 10* and I want to share my application between my personal PC (The host) and some other computers linked to the same home network (Clients).

I changed a line on *httpd-vhosts.conf* file to let the application be accessible from other machines in the network from this:

```
Require lacal
```

to this:

```
Require all granted
```

The problem is that the default virtual host (*localhost*) is accessible from those clients using the host's ip adress like this **192.168.###.###/** but not my customized virtualhost (*tilelli on this case*). Here is the content of *httpd-vhosts.conf* file now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6krhA.png)

I tried to access it via **192.168.###.###/tilelli/** and directly via **tilelli/** but didn't work.

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: If you dont want `localhost` to be accessable, then put it back to `Require local` thats one of the points of defining Virtual Hosts, they can be different from each other

Answer (score 0):

If you define a Virtual Host Servername as `tilelli` then Apache will serve that site when it sees that domain name in the connection request i.e. `http://tilelli`.

If you have a local (company) DNS Server, add that domain to it, pointing to your WAMPServers PC's IP Address. If you dont have a local DNS Server, then change the HOSTS file on the PC's that need to see this server so they know where to look for it

HOSTS FILE

```
192.168.xxx.yyy tilelli
```

You do have to change each and every one of the other PC unfortunately.